# Issues in display layout page in html

Tags: html, css

I have created simple mailchimp template. It works fine in localhost,

but when I send to mail, the layout has 2 mistakes from exact output.

That is, 1. displayed border-right and 2. The text "Environmentally Friendly Protective Coatings" did not show next to logo.

In localhost jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/aj3uhcdp/

Here is my page layout http://s22.postimg.org/5d4ur21n5/Untitled_2_copy.png

I used the following css by manual:

```
 span {
        text-align:center;
        font-size:24px;
        padding-left:231px;
        width:350px;
        padding-top:0px;
        margin-top:-102px !important;
        float:left;
        line-height:1.5em;
        color:#fff !important;
    }   
     .columnsContainer:last-of-type .templateColumn{
        border-right:0px;
    }
```

These css is not working , when i send email layout.

Can anyone help me? thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to hide the last border or show it?

Comment: need to hide.. thanks

Comment: can you please exact css? becuase., i don't have installed drop box... thanks..

Comment: Yes, i tried all possible ways, and used your css.. still nothing happen.. the text didn't display on the image.. it shows either out of the top or left or bottom of the image... thanks.. in localhost it works fine..

Comment: Make the text size or your logo image smaller. It's being pushed down because it simply cannot fit next to the logo.

Comment: i tried to reduce font-size.... but still nothing happen..

Answer (score 1):

See snippet below

```css
body,
#bodyTable,
#bodyCell {
  height: 100% !important;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100% !important;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.templateColumn {
  border-right: 1px solid #AAA;
}
.columnsContainer:last-of-type .templateColumn {
  border-right: 0px;
}
img,
a img {
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
p {
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 0;
}
a {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.ReadMsgBody {
  width: 100%;
}
.ExternalClass {
  width: 100%;
}
.ExternalClass,
.ExternalClass p,
.ExternalClass span,
.ExternalClass font,
.ExternalClass td,
.ExternalClass div {
  line-height: 100%;
}
table,
td {
  mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
  mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
}
#outlook a {
  padding: 0;
}
img {
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
body,
table,
td,
p,
a,
li,
blockquote {
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
#bodyCell {
  padding: 0;
}
.mcnImage {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.mcnTextContent img {
  height: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="templateHeader">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" class="templateContainer">
        <tr>
          <td valign="top" class="headerContainer" style="padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px;">
            <table class="mcnImageBlock" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
              <tbody class="mcnImageBlockOuter">
                <tr>
                  <td style="padding:9px" class="mcnImageBlockInner" valign="top">
                    <table class="mcnImageContentContainer" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="mcnImageContent" style="padding-right: 9px; padding-left: 9px; padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0;" valign="top">

                            <h4 class="null"><span 
  style="color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-left: 260px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-family: arial,helvetica neue,helvetica,sans-serif;
  top: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 300px;
">Environmentally Friendly Protective Coatings</span></h4> 
                            <img alt="" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/74b6bdda18d16b31a24e81ec6/images/46632b56-a0a7-4c6d-9202-62dcf54f78e2.jpg" style="max-width:600px; padding-bottom: 0;display:table-cell;float:left;  width:100%;vertical-align: bottom;"
                            class="mcnImage" align="left" width="600">



                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- BEGIN BODY // -->
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="templateBody">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" class="templateContainer">
        <tr>
          <td valign="top" class="bodyContainer" style="padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px;">
            <table class="mcnTextBlock" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
              <tbody class="mcnTextBlockOuter">
                <tr>
                  <td class="mcnTextBlockInner" valign="top">
                    <table class="mcnTextContentContainer" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="mcnTextContent" style="padding: 9px 18px;color: #CCCCCC;font-family: Arial,&quot;helvetica neue&quot: ;,helvetica,sans-serif: ;font-size: 22px;font-weight: normal;line-height: 200%;" valign="top">
                            <h4 class="null"><span style="color:#cccccc"><span style="font-size:22px;font-family:arial,helvetica neue,helvetica,sans-serif">3 Easy Liquid Rubber Solutions For Your Customers</span></span></h4>

                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- // END BODY -->
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align="center" valign="top">
    <!-- BEGIN COLUMNS // -->
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="templateColumns">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top">
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" class="templateContainer">
            <tr>
              <td align="left" valign="top" class="columnsContainer" width="33%">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="templateColumn">
                  <tr>
                    <td valign="top" class="leftColumnContainer">
                      <table class="mcnCaptionBlock" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <tbody class="mcnCaptionBlockOuter">
                          <tr>
                            <td class="mcnCaptionBlockInner" style="padding:9px;" valign="top">
                              <table class="mcnCaptionBottomContent" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="false">
                                <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td class="mcnTextContent" style="padding: 0px 9px; font-family: Arial,&quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 16px;" valign="top" width="164"> <span style="color:#cccccc">Leaky Barn Roofs</span>

                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td class="mcnCaptionBottomImageContent" style="padding:10px 9px 9px 9px;" align="left" valign="top">
                                      <img alt="" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/74b6bdda18d16b31a24e81ec6/images/06c313ab-701e-4821-8e83-de852f0d901a.jpg" style="max-width:128px;" class="mcnImage" width="128">
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td class="mcnTextContent" style="padding: 0px 9px; font-family: Arial,&quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 12px;" valign="top" width="164"> <span style="color:#cccccc">Liquid Rubber MetalSafe Sealants provide corrosion protection, waterproofing and color restoration to aged rusting steel barn roofs, outlastingtypical barn roof paints for years. Our self priming coatings require only a washed surface without the removal of any rust and can be applied with a brush, roller or paint sprayer. Standard &amp; custom color top-coats are available.</span>

                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                </tbody>
                              </table>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                      <table class="mcnCaptionBlock" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <tbody class="mcnCaptionBlockOuter">
                          <tr>
                            <td class="mcnCaptionBlockInner" style="padding:9px;" valign="top">
                              <table class="mcnCaptionBottomContent" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="false">
                                <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td class="mcnCaptionBottomImageContent" style="padding:0 9px 9px 9px;" align="left" valign="top">
                                      <img alt="" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/74b6bdda18d16b31a24e81ec6/images/ec1bfef3-3b43-4356-ae66-ba8602719173.jpg" style="max-width:186px;" class="mcnImage" width="164">
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td class="mcnTextContent" style="padding:0 9px 0 9px;" valign="top" width="164"></td>
                                  </tr>
                                </tbody>
                              </table>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
              <td align="left" valign="top" class="columnsContainer" width="33%">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="templateColumn">
                  <tr>
                    <td valign="top" class="centerColumnContainer">
                      <table class="mcnCaptionBlock" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <tbody class="mcnCaptionBlockOuter">
                          <tr>
                            <td class="mcnCaptionBlockInner" style="padding:9px;" valign="top">
                              <table class="mcnCaptionBottomContent" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="false">
                                <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td class="mcnTextContent" style="padding: 0px 9px; font-family: Arial,&quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 16px;" valign="top" width="164"> <span style="color:#cccccc">Waterproof Planter</span>

                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td class="mcnCaptionBottomImageContent" style="padding:10px 9px 9px 9px;" align="left" valign="top">
                                      <img alt="" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/74b6bdda18d16b31a24e81ec6/images/a15958de-0729-4ccd-8228-66f5e9a80e0e.jpg" style="max-width:128px;" class="mcnImage" width="128">
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td class="mcnTextContent" style="padding: 0px 9px; font-size: 12px;" valign="top" width="164"> <span style="color:#cccccc">Simple and easy to do. Waterproof and preserve your wood planter boxes. Untreated wood planter boxes start to decay from the harmful effects of water and ultraviolet light. Two thick coats of Liquid Rubber Waterproof Sealant will provide long lasting and full protection that will secure your planter boxes for years to come.</span>

                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                </tbody>
                              </table>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                      <table class="mcnCaptionBlock" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <tbody class="mcnCaptionBlockOuter">
                          <tr>
                            <td class="mcnCaptionBlockInner" style="padding:9px;" valign="top">
                              <table class="mcnCaptionBottomContent" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="false">
                                <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td class="mcnCaptionBottomImageContent" style="padding:0 9px 9px 9px;" align="left" valign="top">
                                      <img alt="" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/74b6bdda18d16b31a24e81ec6/images/e6686072-3933-4150-b034-eef1599bc277.jpg" style="max-width:186px;" class="mcnImage" width="164">
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td class="mcnTextContent" style="padding:0 9px 0 9px;" valign="top" width="164"></td>
                                  </tr>
                                </tbody>
                              </table>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
              <td align="left" valign="top" class="columnsContainer" width="33%">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="templateColumn">
                  <tr>
                    <td valign="top" class="rightColumnContainer">
                      <table class="mcnCaptionBlock" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <tbody class="mcnCaptionBlockOuter">
                          <tr>
                            <td class="mcnCaptionBlockInner" style="padding:9px;" valign="top">
                              <table class="mcnCaptionBottomContent" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="false">
                                <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td class="mcnTextContent" style="padding: 0px 9px; font-family: Arial,&quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 16px;" valign="top" width="164"> <span style="color:#cccccc">RV Roof Repair Boxes</span>

                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td class="mcnCaptionBottomImageContent" style="padding:10px 9px 9px 9px;" align="left" valign="top">
                                      <img alt="" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/74b6bdda18d16b31a24e81ec6/images/544220eb-ac2e-42df-bff5-7c23cbf5b70f.jpg" style="max-width:125px;" class="mcnImage" width="125">
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td class="mcnTextContent" style="padding: 0px 9px; font-size: 12px;" valign="top" width="164"> <span style="color:#cccccc">You may be surprised at how inexpensive and simple it can be to repair an RV, motor home or camper yourself. Using a combination of Liquid Rubber Smooth Sealant and Liquid Rubber Seam Tape, any do-it-yourself customer can seal a leaky roof, whether it's made of EPDM, TPO, fiberglass or aluminum.</span>

                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                </tbody>
                              </table>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                      <table class="mcnCaptionBlock" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <tbody class="mcnCaptionBlockOuter">
                          <tr>
                            <td class="mcnCaptionBlockInner" style="padding:9px;" valign="top">
                              <table class="mcnCaptionBottomContent" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="false">
                                <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td class="mcnCaptionBottomImageContent" style="padding:0 9px 9px 9px;" align="left" valign="top">
                                      <img alt="" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/74b6bdda18d16b31a24e81ec6/images/dd773540-6d80-459a-b0ff-6e1002c906ba.jpg" style="max-width:186px;" class="mcnImage" width="164">
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td class="mcnTextContent" style="padding:0 9px 0 9px;" valign="top" width="164"></td>
                                  </tr>
                                </tbody>
                              </table>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- // END COLUMNS -->
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

Comment: to the image try .mcnImageContent img{} , or in your img within the td

Comment: but now, it didn't show border-right.. thats right.. but the 'Environmentally text..' remains same.. thanks

Comment: are you sure you are adding the classes correctly ? Can you upload the whole template folder online ( dropbox ) ? it would be helpful.
As for the border you can try .templateColumn:last-child {border-right:0} or use border-right color same as the background to hide it.. you can add it inline in your table. Plz upload complete files

Comment: all are working fine in localhost.. but in layout page 'Environmentally text..' remains same..' remains same..

Comment: now look like this http://s13.postimg.org/54n9qbaqv/Untitled_2_copy.png thanks @awrak

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to be a spoilsport but some of your css is too advanced for most email-clients:

```
.columnsContainer:last-of-type
```

for example will not be supported by any Outlook version or GoogleMail. For details about supported CSS see [Campaignmonitor](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/).

I would recommend not to use css-borders because they don't work well in email-clients. Too solve your problem quickly I would suggest the following:

1. To avoid the border-problem put 5 columns into the "column"-table so that you have 3 text-columns and 2 "border"-columns in between. You can use little GIF-images to fake the borders. Like so:

   ```
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td width="33%">// your left column-Table here</td>
     <td width="1%">// put a little image as a border here</td>
     <td width="32%">// your center column-Table here</td>
     <td width="1%">// put a little image as a border here</td>
     <td width="33%">// your right column-Table here</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   ```
2. To solve the headline-problem put the text directly into header-image via photoshop. You can add the text to the alt-tag so that users that don't see the images can still read it.